# Google Apps Marketplace SSO requirement

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I am considering developing an application for the Apps for Business Marketplace.  I see that new rules takes affect on November 19th.  Referring to the new documentation (https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/) I do not see that any SSO requirement exists.  There is allot of talk about migrating to new sign on methods, but I see no mention of sign on requirements.

What are the sign on requirements as of November 19th?

If SSO continues to be required or if I publish before Nov. 19th, my application requires security token from my API, in order to carry out API exchanges.  To get this token a user/pass exchange is required one time.  They would never need to enter a user/pass for my app after that.  Will a one time exchange for the security token be denied under a SSO requirement?

For example the statement regarding SSO that an app cannot do is:

> > The end user should not be required to enter a username and password when invoking an application from within Google Apps.  (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/sso)

In my case it would not be required for the user to enter every time, just on the initial creation of the account.  After that I would retain the token from my site, encrypted with the Installed App.

Would my app be denied for requiring this one time exchange under the SSO policy?

Mark

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use SSO (or should if at all possible) -- see [this part of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/intro): Besides, that is a better practice and should make your users feel more trust for your application.

Comment: >> You will have to use SSO (or should if at all possible)It is the should if at all possible part that I am trying rule out.  One time is a compromise for us.  For our business model it is not possible to completely defer to SSO and it would not make our users more comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather (note that I'm building my first marketplace app) you should not prompt users to enter username/password **on your site**.  I am creating user record & storing token behind the scenes. So the user sees Google authorization screen, agrees to let my app use some data, accepts and sign-in right away without any prompt to create an account. After this, user will not be prompted in the future because I have their google id linked to a user record.

From their site - https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/sso#user_experience
[image]

As long as you don't have any intermediate screen, your app should be approved.